# .NET MAUI Shell TabBar does not behave as expected

Tags: ios, uitabbar, .net-maui, custom-renderer

In our .Net MAUI iOS app, we use Shell TabBar:

```
<TabBar>
    <Tab Title="Home" Icon="{StaticResource IconHome}">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="Coverage&#10;Calculator" Icon="{StaticResource IconCalculator}" >
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate calculator:CoverageCalculatorPage}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="Distributor&#10;Locator" Icon="{StaticResource IconLocator}">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate locator:DistributorsLocatorPage}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="Scan&#10;QR Code" Icon="{StaticResource IconQrScanner}">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate qrScanner:QrScannerPage}" />
    </Tab>        
    <Tab Title="More" Icon="{StaticResource IconMore}">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate more:MoreFeaturesPage}" />
    </Tab>
</TabBar>
```

As you can see, some tab titles have two lines. To show both lines, and to center the titles' texts, I use custom renderer:

```
internal class MyShellRenderer : ShellRenderer
{
    protected override IShellTabBarAppearanceTracker CreateTabBarAppearanceTracker()
    {
        return new MyCreateTabBarAppearanceTracker();
    }

    public class MyCreateTabBarAppearanceTracker : ShellTabBarAppearanceTracker, IShellTabBarAppearanceTracker
    {
        void IShellTabBarAppearanceTracker.SetAppearance(UITabBarController controller, ShellAppearance appearance)
        {
            base.SetAppearance(controller, appearance);

            var items = controller.TabBar.Items;

            if (items == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
            {
                if (items[i] == null) continue;
                else
                {
                    UITabBarItem item_temp = items[i];
                    UIView view = item_temp.ValueForKey(new Foundation.NSString("view")) as UIView;
                    UILabel label = view.Subviews[1] as UILabel;
                    label.Lines = 2;
                    label.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;
                    label.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this custom renderer, the goal is achieved only partially. Here is how the TabBar looks at the beginning:

[image: Initial look]

The titles are centered, but only the first line shows up.

If the app is placed in the background, when it re-appears, all tabs have now two lines, but the text is not centered:

[image]

If I touch a tab, the texts get centered:

[image]

But the text of the second tab is truncated.

And the 2nd line of the fourth tab that has two words, loses the second word (wrapped to the 3rd line).

And when the phone is turned to landscape view, the labels are distorted even more:

[image]

Only one line shows up, but wrapped to occupy both lines.

How can this behavior be fixed? I.e. 1) how to make the text to show both centered lines initially, and 2) how to increase the tabs' width to avoid truncating, and 3) how to fix the landscape view?

Comment: Would you mind creating a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) via github repo link?

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT
Please see it here: https://github.com/DavidShochet/MauiApp1

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Could you please add the `StaticResource` for the icon to your project?

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT Hi, could you please clarify this to me? Where exactly and what exactly should I add? Thanks!

Comment: The icon for each tap. I need these icons in the project.

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT The icons are not images, but glyphs, it is font fa_solid.ttf in Resources/Fonts. The app contains everything.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! As we know, `UITabBarButton` implements from `UIView`, and there is no public API to change it. I will try to take a survey to see if we can figure it out. I also see you post the same issue on the `MS Q&A`, you can continue following it.